# How to get multiple matches with using LINQ query in a string array?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function that takes "params string[] requested"
as input and is supposed to use readline to get input from the user and see if any match and if anything matches then return what matches

```
static string inputCheck(params string[] requested){
    string? userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    IEnumerable<string> selected = requested.Where(n => n == userInput);  
    if (selected != null) return selected; //Error is here
    return "Nothing Please Try again";
}
```

The error I get is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string' (csharp0029)"

I would prefer a solution that uses linq

Comment: If it matter the error is on the word selected

Comment: What about `if(requested.Any(x => x == userInput)) return userInput;`?  And FYI `Where` is never going to return `null`.

Comment: `selected` is a collection of strings.  If you want to return a single string, how will you determine which one in the collection to return?

Comment: You probably want to return `selected.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: .any returns a bool and I want it to return the string/character it found

and is .First the only way to do it or does something else just return them all? (asking this for the future)

Comment: `Where` will return them all but it will never be `null`. It will be empty (which you can check for with `if (selected.Any()) return selected`)

Comment: The standard for method names in C# is to use Pascal-case, not camel-case. In other words, they start with a capital, not lower-case.

Comment: forgot camel-case is only for variables

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
static string inputCheck(params string[] requested){
    string? userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    var selected = requested.Where(n => n == userInput).FirstOrDefault(); <<<<===
    if (selected != null) return selected; //Error is here
    return "Nothing Please Try again";
}
```

Why? `Where` returns an enumerable of the matches (even if there is only one). `FirstOrDefault` will return the first one from the list or null if not found

Or even

```
static string inputCheck(params string[] requested){
    string? userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    var selected = requested.FirstOrDefault(n => n == userInput);  
    if (selected != null) return selected; //Error is here
    return "Nothing Please Try again";
}
```

given that `FirstOrDefault` takes an optional predicate

another alternative was

```
static string inputCheck(params string[] requested){
    string? userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    var selected = requested.Where(n => n == userInput);  
    if (selected.Any()) return selected.First(); 
    return "Nothing Please Try again";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns `string` but you return a kind of list inside of your method. Solution:

```cs
    public static List<string> InputCheck(params string[] requested)
    {
        Console.Write("search: ");
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        var filteredList = requested
            .Where(n => n == userInput)
            .ToList();

        return filteredList;
    }
```

..so you can call the method like this:

```cs
var yourArray = new[]
{
    "lorem",
    "ipsum",
    "dolor",
    "sit",
    "amet",
    "lorem",
    "ipsum",
    "dolor",
    "sit",
    "amet"
};

var results = YourClass.InputCheck(yourArray);

if(results.Any())
{ 
   foreach (var result in results)
      Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: you have enlightened me on some new concepts I could never have known thank you

Comment: I updated, check it again pls.